# JavaScript - AngularJS promise not returning anything

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jasmine

I am trying to return a simple HTTP post on a unit test with `Jasmine` but it seems to not work. The application works fine on the web. I have tested several isolated functions. But this won't work.

```
describe('Service: Auth',function(){

    beforeEach(function () {
        module('ui.router');
        module('main');
        module('users');
    });

    var AuthFactory, httpBackend;

    beforeEach(inject(function($httpBackend, _AuthFactory_) {
        httpBackend = $httpBackend;
        AuthFactory = _AuthFactory_;
    }));

    it('should return POST', function() {
        AuthFactory.signIn({inputUser: {username: "admin"}, passInput: {password: "adminpass"}}).then(
            function(result) {
                console.log('======== SUCCESS ========');
                console.log(result);
            },
            function(err) {
                console.log('======== ERROR ========');
                console.log(err);
            },
            function(progress) {
                console.log('======== PROGRESS ========');
                console.log(progress);
            }
        );
        console.log('HTTP call finished.');
        expect(1).toBe(1);
    });

});
```

and here is the **factory**:

```
angular.module('users').factory('AuthFactory', ['$http', function($http) {

    var AuthFactory = {};

    AuthFactory.signIn = function(data) {
        return $http.post('http://127.0.0.1:3000/api/AuthFactoryServ/signIn', data);
    };

    AuthFactory.signOut = function(data) {
        return $http.post('http://127.0.0.1:3000/api/AuthFactoryServ/signOut', data);
    };

    return AuthFactory;

}]);
```

This is what I get:

```
PhantomJS 1.9.8 (Windows 7 0.0.0): Executed 0 of 1 SUCCESS (0 s
LOG: Object{$$state: Object{status: 0}, success: function (fn)
{ ... }, error: function (fn) { ... }}
PhantomJS 1.9.8 (Windows 7 0.0.0): Executed 0 of 1 SUCCESS (0 s
LOG: 'HTTP call finished.'
PhantomJS 1.9.8 (Windows 7 0.0.0): Executed 0 of 1 SUCCESS (0 s
PhantomJS 1.9.8 (Windows 7 0.0.0): Executed 1 of 1 SUCCESS (0 s
PhantomJS 1.9.8 (Windows 7 0.0.0): Executed 1 of 1 SUCCESS (0 secs / 0.022 secs)
```

I have tested the HTTP calls via Postman and it successfully returns data back. So... what am I doing wrong?

Thank you.

Comment: @AaronGates I just want to test to see if my service functions work...  hmmm. I created a new function in the factory method like AuthFactory.test to return a string and it successfully returned that string when I put it inside the Jasmine test.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `AuthFactory.signIn` is asynchronous and returns a promise - your test function is finished before the promise is resolved.

You need to tell Jasmine that it should [wait for the asynchronous test to complete](http://jasmine.github.io/2.0/introduction.html#section-Asynchronous_Support):

```
it('should return POST', function(done) {
  var result = AuthFactory.signIn({inputUser: {username: "admin"}, passInput: {password: "adminpass"}}).then(
      function(result) {
          console.log('======== SUCCESS ========');
          console.log(result);
      },
      function(err) {
          console.log('======== ERROR ========');
          console.log(err);
      },
      function(progress) {
          console.log('======== PROGRESS ========');
          console.log(progress);
      }
  );
  result.then(function(){
    console.log('HTTP call finished.');
    expect(1).toBe(1);
  }).finally(done); //here we hook Jasmine callback to promise chain
});
```

Comment: Oh, I see. Well, when I run that, I get: `TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'result.then(function(){` on the line `}).always(done);`

But I don't understand....

Comment: @djp I've changed `always` to `finally` since that's what's available in [$q](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q)

Comment: try removing ```var result``` and chain ```result.then``` directly off AuthFactory.signIn